# Issues in executing Stored Procedure with Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014, sqlsrv

I'm Using Codeigniter Version 3.1.10 and using SQLSRV as database Driver

I been trying to Execute Stored Procedure with Codeigniter
My Stored Procedure Query is

```
    $sp = "SP_AffniGetReports  @startdate=?,@enddate=?,@interval=?,@device_id=?,@limit=?,@offset=?";
    $params = array($from_date,$to_date,$rpt_time_interval,$meter_id,$offset,$limit);
    $result = $this->db->query($sp,$params,false);
    $result = $this -> db -> get();
```

Getting this error

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Must specify table to select from.

SELECT *
```

after checking above error I have printed the Codeigniter generated Stored Procedure query and I got

```
SP_AffniGetReports @startdate='2019-06-21 12:00:01',@enddate='2019-06-27 11:05:59',@interval='60',@device_id='101',@limit=0,@offset='30'
```

as the compiled query!

I have tried every modifications such as using "EXEC","CALL" in query and references for the past 2 days. But I'm Unable to execute stored procedure.

Now I tried to run the same query with Normal PHP script using SQLSRV, the Stored Procedure Executed. My PHP script is

```
$procedure_params = array('2019-06-10 00:00:01','2019-06-27 00:00:59','1','101','0','30');
$sql = "EXEC SP_AffniGetReports @startdate=?,@enddate=?,@interval=?,@device_id=?,@limit=?,@offset=?";
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, $procedure_params);
```

And I got the result! But i can't find the issue with Codeigniter's Stored Procedure

Comment: try resetting old queries by  $this->db->reset_query(); Some previous partially generated queries may cause this issue!

Comment: Tried your suggestion but still same problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found why this issue occurred my syntax mistake. The code should be

```
$query = $this->db->query($sp,$params,false);
$result = $query->result();
```

> By using  $result = $this -> db -> get(); Codeigniter is trying to create new query along with Stored Procedure. This the cause of my issue.